# Get the next hidden input value

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure

```
<tr>
        <td class="product-remove">
            <div><a href="#" class="remove remove-favorite-items" title="Remove this item">×</a></div>
        </td>

        <td class="product-thumbnail">
            <a href="http://localhost/test/product/patient-ninja/">
                <img width="90" height="90" src="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/hoodie_3_front.jpg" class="attachment-shop_thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="cd_6_angle"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="product-name">
            <input type="hidden" value="50" class="product_id_hidden">   <-- want to get this value
            <a href="http://localhost/test/product/patient-ninja/">Patient Ninja</a>
        </td>
        <td>


            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="checkforstock('http://localhost/test/wp-content/plugins/dvin-wcwl/add-to-cart.php?wlist_item_id=7','In','false');">Add To Cart</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

i want to get the value of the hidden input, when i click on `<div><a href="#" class="remove remove-favorite-items" title="Remove this item">×</a>`

what i done is the following

```
        var product_id = $(this).parent('td').find('input[type=hidden]').val();    // get the product id
```

how can do that ?

Comment: `var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : Use `.closest()` to find parent `tr` and then use `.find()` to get hidden input.

```
var product_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=hidden]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$(function(){
$(".remove.remove-favorite-items").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.product_id_hidden').val();
    alert("Deteting item id: " + product_id);
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/1pj7q14p/1/